# Discovering jni4net samples

Tags: java, .net, jni4net

I'm discovering the [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net). This is the technology used to provide the bridge between Java and .NET. So, I created new Eclipse Java project and copied the sample code from jni4net-0.8.6.0-bin/samples/myCSharpDemoCalc->MyCalcUsageInJava.java into this project. However the code cannot be compiled because two imports "mycsharpdemocalc.DemoCalc" and "mycsharpdemocalc.ICalc" cannot be found. I don't understand how to integrate/import mycsharpdemocalc.c into the Java project so that the code could be compiled.

```
import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;

import java.io.IOException;

import mycsharpdemocalc.DemoCalc;
import mycsharpdemocalc.ICalc;

public class MyCalcUsageInJava {
    public static void main(String arsg[]) throws IOException {
        Bridge.init();
        Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new java.io.File("MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll"));

        ICalc calc = new DemoCalc();
        final int result = calc.MySuperSmartFunctionIDontHaveInJava("Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything");

        System.out.printf("Answer to the Ultimate Question is : " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the classes or jars on the classpath?

Comment: The only thing that includes this sample is Calc.cs, MyCSharpDemoCalc.c, MyCSharpDemoCalc.sln, MyCalcUsageInJava.java and MyCSharpDemoCalc.dll. So I putted MyCSharpDemoCalc.dll into the classpath, but the code cannot be still compiled.

Comment: @YouKuper Have you solved the problem? I've got the same issue...

Comment: @David C. No, I didn´t solve this problem. Probably ´cause I don´t have experience in this topic. Therefore I just selected another approach for solving my problem instead of using .NET assembly. But I marked this thread as "Solved", because I guess Mr. Pavel Savara has explained possible reasons. I just don´t have time to debug the code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ReadMe](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/blob/master/content/samples/) in each sample directory. 
You have to use proxygen tool to generate the proxies (which are used in the java code).
There is generateProxies.cmd batch to do that.
More complex things may need config file for proxygen.

Also there is community [Wiki](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/wiki)

Comment: After compiling this project, I tried to run it. The following error message was shown: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mycsharpdemocalc.DemoCalc.__ctorDemoCalc0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;)V
 at mycsharpdemocalc.DemoCalc.__ctorDemoCalc0(Native Method)
 at mycsharpdemocalc.DemoCalc.<init>(DemoCalc.java:25)
 at MyCalcUsageInJava.main(MyCalcUsageInJava.java:13). What is wrong, could you tell me please?

Comment: You forgot to initialize the bridge I guess. Or you didn't register all DLLs.

Comment: @PavelSavara I've the same issue using your library. I've loaded my dll and put in my lib folder both `jni4net.j-0.8.6.0.jar`, 
`jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll` and `jni4net.n.w32.v40-0.8.6.0.dll`. Proxygen generated a java class in jvm folder and a cs file in clr folder. I'm using only the first one. Is it correct?

Comment: You have to compile the generated .cs files too, because they contain the bridging part. Resulting DLL should be loaded and registered too.
Sample assumes MyCSharpDemoCalc.j4n.dll